# If $B \subseteq A$, why is $\{ B \}$ not in the power set of $A$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Define $B = \{1\}$ and $A=\{1, 2\}$.  Then the power set of $A$ is $\mathcal P(A)= \{ \emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, A \}$.  Let $C= \{ B \} = \{ \{1 \}\}$.  Why is $C \notin \mathcal P(A)$?

I dont see why $C$ is not an element of $\mathcal P(A)$, because with the brackets around B you get the set of the set containing B. In the Power Set of A i see that we have a set containing the set with 1. Is it wrong because the one in the power set isnt the set containing the set with 1. I dont know how else to read the power set though. Its a set with the element set containing one.

Comment: The statement should read "...then $B\in P(a)$."

Comment: The question is the {B} ∈ P(A)

Comment: Right, and you are correct: that statement is generally false. What *is* true, as you suspected, is that $B\in P(A)$. Sorry if I was not clear.

Comment: No thank you for answering. So B is an element of P(A) but not {B}. Why though? I see that set containing the set 1 in both. I can read the power set as, the set containing the set 1 as well as the one for {B}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like to think of simple sets as boxes.  Then $B$ is a box that contains the number $1$.  And $\{B\}$ is a box that contains a box that contains the number $1$.  So, if $A$ is a set, then $P(A)$ is the set of boxes that contain elements from $A$.

Comment: Thank you. If i changed the problem to {B} ⊆ P(A) then would the answer be true correct?

Comment: Yes, since $\{B\}\subseteq P(A)$ means that each element of $\{B\}$ (namely, $B$ only) is an element of $P(A)$, i.e. is  a subset of $A$.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you guys

Answer (score 3):

$\{B\}$ is a set with one element; namely, $B$. (The fact that $B$ itself may be a set is irrelevant here). Saying that $\{B\}\in P(A)$ is saying that $\{B\}$ is a subset of $A$ (since $P(A)$ is the set of all subsets of $A$). Now, what does it mean for $\{B\}$ to be a subset of $A$? It means that each element of $\{B\}$ is an element of $A$. But the only element of $\{B\}$ is $B$ itself, which is not an element of $A$ (not in your specific example, nor in most examples that this question contemplates). Rather, the *elements* of $B$ are elements of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's check.  We know $\{B\}=\big\{\{1\}\big\}$ and $P(\{1,2\})=\big\{\emptyset,\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\big\}$.  So:

- Does $\big\{\{1\}\big\}=\emptyset$.  No.
- Does $\big\{\{1\}\big\}=\{1\}$.  No.
- Does $\big\{\{1\}\big\}=\{2\}$.  No.
- Does $\big\{\{1\}\big\}=\{1,2\}$.  No.

So $B \not\in P(\{1,2\})$.

Note that $\big\{\{1\}\big\}$ can be informally thought of as "a bag containing a bag containing $1$" whereas $\{1\}$ is "a bag containing $1$".

Comment: Thank you.  If i changed the problem to {B} ⊆ P(A) then would the answer be true correct?

Comment: Indeed it would: each element in $\{B\}$ is also in $P(A)$.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

We have $$P(A)=\{C : C \subset A\}.$$
So $$b \in A \Longrightarrow \{b\} \in P(A)$$
 but 
$$\require{cancel}B \subset A \cancel{\Longrightarrow}\{B\} \in P(A)$$ since $\{B\} \notin A,$ however
 $$B \subset A \Longrightarrow \{B\} \subset P(A) \Longrightarrow  \{B\}\in P(P(A)).$$